# How can I maintain ubuntu 12.04 servers without a mailserver running on them

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, email-server

How can I run an ubuntu 12.04 server without a mailserver running on it?

This is for improved security and easy mantenance. I don't need mails processed on the system, I read the log files instead.

Some packages install a mailserver although they can be used without mail. What is an easy way to live with that? I don't want to mess with apt-get or find a solution for every single case.

Could I install a dummy mailserer? Or the most simple mail server package of them all and disable it in the config?

Do the various packages install different mailservers, or do some of them install postfix, others exim4?

What could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need a local mailserver on a linux system.

Try the minimal setup (local mail only).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the MTA of the mail server, then you can satisfy the dependency with lsb-invalid-mta.

sudo apt-get install lsb-invalid-mta

There is a metapackage called [mail-transport-agent](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/mail-transport-agent) with the dependencies that satisfy the use of a MTA and there is lsb-invalid-mta with is just a dummy sendmail that do nothing.

That way you can run an Ubuntu server without a mail server. And if you need to get mail off the system to a mail hub you can use ssmtp.